# Matplotlib ArtistAnimation showing multiple elements in one step

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I've been using matplotlib for a while to create plots but have just now discovered the `animation` options. I want to show a series of plots (not just individual elements) in an animation using `animation.ArtistAnimation`.

Unfortunately, I can't get it to animate multiple plotted elements at a time. Here's a minimal example to explain what I mean:

```py
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()

ims = []
for _ in range(10):
    im1, = plt.plot([random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)], [random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)])
    im2, = plt.plot([random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)], [random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)])
    ims.append((im1,))
    ims.append((im2,))
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims)

ani.save('im.mp4')
```

This randomly generates two lines `im1`, `im2` 10x. I always want to see both `im1` and `im2` at the same time. But this only shows one line at a time.
If I comment `ims.append((im1,))`, the background is full of static lines, but it still just animates one line.
I also tried to combine `im1` and `im2` using `im1 + im2` or `[im1, im2]`, but both lead to errors.

Extra question: Is there any reason why `blit=False` by default? I thought, it's supposed to improve performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simply to add both artists to the list at once.

The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation.html) talks about "a collection of artists that represent what needs to be enabled on each frame", so what `ims` needs to be is a list of lists (one per frame) of artists (any per frame).

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()

ims = []
for _ in range(10):
    im1, = plt.plot([random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)], [random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)])
    im2, = plt.plot([random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)], [random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)])
    ims.append([im1, im2])
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims)

ani.save('im.mp4')
```

Comment: Ah, it's that simple! :D I tried to add the list similarly to how I added each individual artist: `ims.append(([im1,im2],))` and that gave me an error. I still don't quite get why I have to pass the individual artists in such a weird way. But this solves my problem; thanks!

Comment: Also, do you know how to decide whether or not to enable `blit`? Why is it disabled by default?

Comment: Also, I have a followup question that you may be able to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61652069/matplotlib-artistanimation-plot-entire-figure-in-each-step

Comment: @CGFoX It's not that weird if you consider that the animation expect this format `[(artists of frame 1,), (artists of frame 2,), ...]` actually :) I don't know for sure but I assume blitting is disabled so that axis ticks and labels can be redrawn. Often when we use blitting it's with a fixed background + a moving artist and it involves redrawing only inside the bounding box (so it's performant but you can't change the scale anymore).