# Matplotlib ArtistAnimation: Plot entire figure in each step

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot

I have an existing function I use for plotting, which I call repeatedly in my program.
I want to use `matplotlib`'s `ArtistAnimation` to save each plot as an "artist" that is shown in one step of the animation.

I know how to use `ArtistAnimation` to show individual elements of the plot in the animation, but not the entire plot.

Here's a simplified example:

```py
import random

def my_plot():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot([random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)], [random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)])
    ax.plot([random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)], [random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)])
    plt.show()
    return ax

ims = []
fig = plt.figure()
for _ in range(5):
    ax = my_plot()
    ims.append((ax,))
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, repeat=False)
ani.save('im.mp4', metadata={'artist':'Guido'})
```

This runs without error, but the resulting video is just blank. The same happens if I return a list of the artists created by `ax.plot()`.

I assume the problem is that I'm calling `plt.figure`/`plt.subfigure` multiple times. But I'm not sure how to avoid that. Do I need to create one figure up front and pass that to each call of `my_plot`? Seems a bit ugly.

Comment: You are not using `something = my_plot()` so the returned value is never used ;)

Comment: Oh, thanks, but that was just a mistake when copying the code. I updated/fixed the question. The problem still remains.

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to tom's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61763712/2745116), I found the main reasons why my animations didn't work and only showed the first frame: I called `plt.show()` in each iteration. Apparently, after the first call, the animations stop working. Removing `plt.show()` and only creating one figure solved the problem:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import random

def my_plot():
    patch = []
    patch.extend(plot([random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)], [random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)]))
    patch.extend(plt.plot([random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)], [random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)]))
    # no plt.show() here!
    return patch

ims = []
fig = plt.figure()   # fig created only once
for _ in range(10):
    patch = my_plot()
    ims.append(patch)  
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, repeat=False)
ani.save('im.mp4', metadata={'artist':'Guido'})
```

Not sure how I could both plot and show the plots directly *and* create an animation. Maybe using `plt.draw()` instead? But that doesn't show anything in my PyCharm IDE...
Anyways, I can live with either or.

Comment: The main problem with your original code (in your question) was that you created multiple figs and axes. `plt.show()` and `draw()` etc are about how you display the plot (and they might also trigger the creation of a new fig, depending on how you have things set up, which would be a problem). So the primary thing you've done to make this work is to do what I suggested: add the plot items to a list and accumulate these lists for `ArtistAnimation`, and use a single fig and axes per full animation.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of saving the axes, you need to save the plots as a list.  (Or maybe you don't want to do this and want to save the axes?  If that's the case, let me know and I'll delete this.  I don't think saving the axes will work though, since the animation works by setting the saved items within a figure visible and invisible, and neither the axes nor the figure will hide/reveal a subset of the plots for each frame in this way.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import random

def my_plot(ax):
    p0, = ax.plot([random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)], [random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)])
    p1, = ax.plot([random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)], [random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)])
    return [p0, p1]   # return a list of the new plots

ims = []
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)  # fig and axes created once
for _ in range(10):
    ps = my_plot(ax)
    ims.append(ps)      # append the new list of plots
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, repeat=False)
ani.save('im.mp4', metadata={'artist':'Guido'})
```

GIF below, but here is some vertical spacing so you can scroll the annoying flashing lines of the page while reading the code

. 
. 
. 
. 
. 
. 
. 
. 
. 
. 
. 
. 
. 
.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You don't need to create an extra `ax` object or pass any argument to the function. But your solution helped me undersand what my real problem was: `plt.show()` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61768420/2745116). I'll still give you the bounty :)

Comment: It's better to get used to the object-orientated techniques as soon as possible :) Calling `plt.something` will only work nicely in the situation where you have one figure, one ax, and your figure is not embedded in an application.