# Matplotlib opening keeps opening new graphs instead of updating one current

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

In a loop matplotlib / animation will open new graphs and wont keep updating a singe current one.
Data in the text file being read is constantly being erased then updated with new info(Can change if needed)
This is what I have:

```
            fig = plt.figure()
            ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
 
 with open('Parsed.txt', 'r') as f:
                pullData = f.read()
                dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
                xar = []
                yar = []
               for eachLine in dataArray:
                        if len(eachLine)>1:
                        x,y = eachLine.split(':')
                        xar.append(str(x))
                        yar.append(int(y))
                        ax1.clear()
                        ax1.bar(xar,yar)
                        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
                        plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib ArtistAnimation: Plot entire figure in each step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61652069/matplotlib-artistanimation-plot-entire-figure-in-each-step)

Comment: You shouldn't have "plt.show()" in your for loop

Comment: What would I do instead? Without it, it wont open a graph. Move it anywhere else and its an error / same issue @OmarAlSuwaidi

Comment: Did you try appending the collection of plots into a list, then using the animation method? As proposed in @BallpointBen suggestion